flutter webview problem when retrieving cookies
I have an issue with WebView on Flutter. I am using the webview_flutter widget and I am trying to redirect the user to a site to log in. I then retrieve the cookies to return to the previous page and call the API that requires these cookies to connect. I am able to redirect, log in, and retrieve the cookies, but not all the cookies. The authorization cookie is not retrieved, so it is impossible to call the API (status 401: unauthorized).
Does anyone have an explanation for this? Any suggestions?
